# Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository';

Tags: spring, annotations, h2

I'm trying to do a custom query in my JPA repo for a simple project im doing with spring and angular and im getting some errors that I can't figure out. All I need is a ID based on a userName for a login system.

My repo

```
package systemphones.backend.repository;

imports...

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT ID FROM USER WHERE USER_NAME = ?1")
    Long getUser(String userName);


}
```

my controller

```
package systemphones.backend.controller;

imports...

import java.util.List;


@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    .
    .
    .

    @GetMapping(path = "/test")
    public Long getUser(@RequestParam String userName) {


        return userRepository.getUser(userName);
    }

    .
    .
    .   
}
```

errors:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Long systemphones.backend.repository.UserRepository.getUser(java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:843) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at systemphones.backend.PhonesellerApplication.main(PhonesellerApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Long systemphones.backend.repository.UserRepository.getUser(java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1248) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Long systemphones.backend.repository.UserRepository.getUser(java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:142) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:209) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:566) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:561) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:551) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:551) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:324) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Sorry for the long post. Hope its clean enough for anyone to help me
Thank you in advance for anyone willing to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
@Query("SELECT ID FROM USER WHERE USER_NAME = ?1")
```

with this:

```
@Query("SELECT ID FROM USER WHERE USER_NAME = ?1", nativeQuery=true)
```

Comment: This seemed to solve the problem :) Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is indicating that there is a problem with the syntax of the JPA query.
Try with the following tweak:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT ID FROM USER WHERE USER_NAME = userName")
    Long getUser(@Param("userName") String userName);

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Didnt work, but the solution above seem to have worked. Thank you for the suggestion though :)